# Simple Palindrome in c++

Tags: c++

Would someone be kind enough to route me in the right direction regarding how to get the correct out with this palindrome checker

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPal(string number){
    for (int i = 0, j = number.length(); i < number.length(), j > 0; i++, j--)
        if (i == j){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

int main(){
    cout << isPal("helleh") << "\n";
        cout << isPal("9009") << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, make sure you initialize j to number.length() - 1. Doing straight length will make you go out of bounds since we start counting at 0. Also, (i == j) is comparing the indices i and j, not the elements.

```
for (int i = 0, j = number.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    if (number[i] != number[j])
        return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be an easy way to do it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool isPal(const std::string& number)
{
  return std::equal(number.begin(), 
                    number.begin() + number.size()/2,
                    number.rbegin());
}
```

Concerning your code, you have to return `false` if any one of the elements does not match. You should *only* return `true` if *all* elements match. Currently, you are returning `true` whenever the length of the string is not `0` because you are comparing indices `i` and `j`, not elements. You need to change your logic:

```
string::size_type len = number.length();

if (len == 0) return true; // corner case

for (string::size_type i = 0, j = len; i < len/2; i++, j--)
{
  if (number[i] != number[j-1]) return false;
}
return true;
```

Also note that you don't have to iterate over the whole number of elements, just one half. But I suggest using the standard library. You can see from the example above that is it harder to introduce bugs when using standard library algorithms.

Comment: yes however it always returns zero? (assuming it means false) new to c++ h and h match from each end... however it doesn't even return true... do I have to use a char array?

Comment: @user3396872 Because you are comparing the indices, and they are only equal if the length of the string is 0! See my edit.

Comment: Not the one down voting you, but possibly because the first statements in your for loop are comparing vs. assigning.

Comment: @Inertiatic Thanks. I think I introduced that in an edit. But the down-vote came first.

Comment: @juanchopanza No problem, happens to all of us. Yea, I think someone is just on a down voting spree. My answer was down voted for a bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

```
bool isPal(string number)
{
   int len = number.length();
   for (int i = 0, j = len-1; j > i ; ++i, --j)
   {
      if ( number[i] != number[j] )
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

bool isPolindrome(string str) {

    long n = str.length();

    for (long i=0; i<n/2; i++) {

        if(str[i] != str[n-1-i]) return false;

    }

    return true;
}

int main() {

    string s;

    cin >> s;

    cout << boolalpha << isPolindrome(s) << endl;

    return 0;

}
```